# How to do SUM based on SELECT DISTINCT on multiple column

Tags: sql

I have a table where there are 3 numeric columns `(a,b,c)` and two categorical column `(x,y)`. I want make a sum for `a ,b and c` but based on each **unique** `x and y` combination. How can I do that ?
I have tried the following code

```
SELECT   
SUM(CAST(t.a as INT64)) as a_,
SUM(CAST(t.b  as INT64)) as b_ ,
SUM(CAST(t.c  as INT64)) as c_,

FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT x ,y FROM <table_name>  
) t
```

Now what I am getting is `a` not found insde `t`

How can I fix that ? what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Sample data would really help your question.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a group by in this case

```
SELECT   
x,
y,
SUM(CAST(t.a as INT64)) as a_,
SUM(CAST(t.b  as INT64)) as b_ ,
SUM(CAST(t.c  as INT64)) as c_

from
<table_name>  
group by x, y
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting the values if they are already numbers?  I think you want:

```
SELECT x, y, SUM(a) as sum_a, SUM(b) as sum_b, SUM(c) as sum_c
FROM t
GROUP BY x, y;
```

If you want the sum of all three (which your question suggests, then you want:

```
SUM(a + b + c) as sum_abc,
```

or:

```
SUM(a) + SUM(b) + SUM(c) as sum_abc
```

These last two are subtly different, if any of the values are `NULL`.  It is not clear which you might want.